# Why is my download speed slow on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, internet, download-speed

Unfortunately I am experiencing slow download speeds on Ubuntu 11.10 but not on Windows Vista. My limited knowledge with Ubuntu and my subsequent flawed research to resolve the matter suggest, it might be a problem with Ath9k.

[image]

Comment: You showed a a screenshot of speedtest.net in Ubuntu, could you perform the same test in Windows and upload the picture for comparison purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wireless it might have something to do with power management. Try this:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

(where wlan0 is the network interface you use)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem on two different machines where the Realtek R8168 wireless network card (use `lspci` to verify) was using the R8169 drivers on install.  This sort of works, depending on the router, but if you did a `dmesg` you'd see the connection failing all of the time, and the throughput dropping down like what you see.  This can also happen with a R8111 card.

Solution: install the [right driver for the R8168.](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2)

I have no idea if this is your real problem, but it sounds similar to my old problem.  Verify the right network drivers are being loaded for your card.